# Drop rows from a dataframe with a non-numeric index

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indexing, numeric

I have been using pandas to do some interesting filtering of CSV files, but have ran into a roadblock.  I am trying to check my index column for garbled text (non-integer) data, and remove those lines.  I've tried removing them from dataframe upon import using conditionals, and i've tried iterating them out afterwards without success.  Here is an example:

```
df = pd.read_csv(file, encoding='cp1252').set_index("numbers")
results = df[df["columnA"].str.contains("search_data") & ~df["columnB"].isin(seach_list)]
#I need to add to the above statement to check column "numbers" which I have set to be the index,
#to catch some expected garbled text and filter it out... because it is
#an integer, I can't use str.contains or isdigit or isalnum, I've tried to do len(df["columns"] < 20 , df.index < 20 .... i've tried 
#i've tried a few other options at this point as well
# after bringing it in, I've also tried iterating through it:
#
for index, row in results.iterrows():
    if not (isinstance( row["numbers"], int )):
         print(str(row["numbers"]))
         #append whole row to new dataframe
#This also didn't work
```

Any thoughts on what I can do?

```
Example data in the "numbers columns = 329381432
Example garbled text in "numbers" column that I am 
trying to keep from importing: äu$ÒÔ”5$ò"Â$”äu$ÒÔ”5$ò
```

As a side note, I had to change the encoding of the pd function so that I can still read all the good data in the files when there was some non utf-8 data... otherwise it would throw an error on import.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use `pd.to_numeric` to convert your `numbers` column to numeric. All non-numeric entries will be coerced to `NaN`, and you can then just drop those rows.

```
df = pd.read_csv(file, encoding='cp1252')
df['numbers'] = pd.to_numeric(df['numbers'], errors='coerce')

df = df.dropna(subset=['numbers']).set_index('numbers')
```